# Disable a command box in Databricks notebook

Tags: azure, azure-databricks

I have a Databricks Notebook. My notebook has several command. some of them is just for my test and I do not want ran them on production.

Is there any way to just disable a command. I do not want to delete them permanently.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

My solution is to set %md as first line, so the cell is interpreted as Markdown and no commands are executed.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).